# how to fetch the recently inserted record amoung the duplicate data

Tags: sql, db2

I have Two table,

**Table 1**

```
A-ID    Name    reg.id
100     shankar 11a
101     kumar   11b
102     Raj     11c
```

**Table 2**

```
A-ID    B-ID    Type   create date  update date
100      1      mail    03/01/17    03/01/2017 9.10
100      2      fax     03/01/17    03/01/2017 9.10
100      3      phone   03/01/17    03/01/2017 9.11
100      4      phone   03/02/17    03/02/2017 10.00
100      5      fax     03/02/17    03/02/2017 10.01
100      6      mail    03/02/17    03/02/2017 10.01
100      7      phone   03/02/17    03/02/2017 10.02
101      4      phone   03/02/17    03/02/2017 10.00
101      5      fax     03/02/17    03/02/2017 10.02
101      6      mail    03/02/17    03/02/2017 10.03
```

here A-ID,foreign key. "Type" value will be inserted many times for the same day but each insert the updated gmts will be inserted with current time stamp, like in this example the "Type" phone for 100 inserted at "03/02/2017 10.00" and "03/02/2017 10.02".
 But all i want the Recent insert for the particular day here"03/02/2017 10.02". the same applies for other "Type" value Fax and email.. but the very recent entry for the particular day should be extracted as out put only onetime?

I want Result like,

```
create date A-ID    reg.id  Type    update date
03/02/17    100     11a     phone   03/02/2017 10.02
03/02/17    100     11a     fax     03/02/2017 10.01
03/02/17    100     11a     mail    03/02/2017 10.01
03/02/17    101     11b     phone   03/02/2017 10.00
03/02/17    101     11b      fax    03/02/2017 10.02
03/02/17    101     11b     mail    03/02/2017 10.03
```

Please help me on writing the inner query ?

Comment: is it mysql/oracle or db2 ?

Comment: i Prefer with Db2

Comment: Prefer with? Do you have option of running it in any database you want?

Comment: the final implementation at DB2 query in JSR batch.. So I want this only with DB2. I will remove other Tags. i added other tags to understand the logic only.. but all i want it in DB2.

Comment: Ok. Check the answers given and comment on them in case you have any doubt.

Answer (score 1):

```html
select B.[create date] , A.[A-ID] , A.[reg.id] , B.[update date]
  FROM Table1 A 
         INNER JOIN Table2 B
             ON  A.A-ID   = B.A-ID
```

Comment: How does that give the solution which OP has? He doesn't just want to join 2 tables. Understand the expected result and then see how can you achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle/DB2 support windows function `row_number() over (partition by` so you can use

```
select * from 
(select 
t.*,row_number() over (partition by A-ID,Type order by "update date" desc) rn
from Table2 t
) t2
left join Table1 t1
on t2.A-ID=T1.A-ID
where t2.rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

In Native SQL:

```
SELECT  CREATE_DATE
        ,A_ID
        ,REG_ID
        ,TYPE
        ,MAX(UPDATE_DATE)
FROM TABLE_1 A,TABLE_2 B
WHERE A.A_ID= B.A_ID
GROUP BY CREATE_DATE
        ,A_ID
        ,REG_ID
        ,TYPE
```